# style a form (select) using javascript, no framework?

Tags: javascript, forms, select, coding-style

anyone know how i can style a  form element with javascript, but without a framework?
Found a nice plugin for jquery but I don't use jquery at all on my website so I want to avoid it if possible..

I want to create a select box that looks like this:

http://iforce.co.nz/i/qebncmoz.png

to clarify, i want to set an image/background on the select box so that I can have a custom dropdown arrow

Answer (score 3):

You can style elements through the style attribute (replacing '-' with camel case) like this:

```
document.getElementById('elem').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

But it's better to put the styles in CSS and just change classes in JavaScript instead:

```
document.getElementById('elem').className = 'roundedCornerButton';
```

Comment: Why would one use Javascript to set the classes instead of setting them directly in the HTML code?

Comment: Only if the style is supposed to change dynamically. If not, then just use HTML class attribute and CSS like you said.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a different element.  <select> can't be used because you can't style it very well using CSS, save for the background colour and font.

The best direction I can point you in is http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect/ - it seems to explain how to do what you want to do pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

You won't need Javascript for that, pure CSS will do.

Check this article for example:
[Style Web Forms Using CSS](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/style-web-forms-css)

Answer (score 1):

The styling is done through CSS, not JS. JQuery is used for shortcuts in Javascript.

There is no "replacement" happening - the  tag is still there under the scene but good use of CSS is what makes it look like that image.

Comment: The select element isn't stylable with CSS, JS **is** required to achieve the functionality with a different element that is styled using CSS to appear as a select element.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of drop down menu replacements out there that don't require a framework. Try Googling `javascript drop down`. See a fancy example [here](http://www.leigeber.com/2008/04/sliding-javascript-dropdown-menu/).

But consider using a framework. 20-50kb are not that much anymore in these times, it's not that much even for a dialup line. Frameworks provide a lot of little helpers for all sorts of tasks and you can link even to [Google hosted versions](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/), with the great likelihood that the user already has them cached.

Answer (score 0):

If the form element has an ID associated, then you can use code similar to the following:

```
elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
elem.style.background = 'white';
```

I assume you want to dynamically change the element style; differently, you don't need JavaScript to obtain what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without javascript see here my question [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

### And if uyou don't want to use any framework then try this

http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect/

Comment: `What I'm asking though is does anyone know of a similar solution but that does not require a javascript framework like jQuery (which is 50kb hence why I dont want to use it just for 1 selectbox)`

Comment: u can't modify selectbox without javascript